# How to set up an sstp vpn connection

Tags: 11.10, installation, vpn

the question is simple: how to set up an sstp vpn connection in ubuntu 11.10?
as of this moment I haven't been able to find a way to make an sstp vpn connection.

Answer (score 1):

As you have not provided any details on your requirements, any solution is as good a any other:

http://unblockvpn.com/support/how-to-set-up-unblock-vpn-sstp-on-linux-ubuntu.html

Comment: Sorry for the downvote, I tried to change it. The answer in the link is perfect, however, I disagree with the comment.